# Using a function in Initcomponents()

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am making a JFrame application in Java , I'm using the Application designer to insert components in my JFrame. In a Jtextarea , I would like to display some text but that text is returned by a function that I wrote in my class. So I thought I can just call the function in the JTextarea value in the initcomponents() which manage the code for my gui components. But the initcomponent method can not be modified(highlighted in grey). Is there a way to do this?

```
public String yes() {
    return "voila";
}
```

Is there a way to do something like this ?

```
private void initcomponent() {
    jTextArea1.setText("some text" + yes());
}
```

Comment: What IDE are you using? some IDEs will not allow you to edit method that initializes the GUI but some IDEs will let you.

Comment: Im using NetBeans

Comment: Do you only want to edit the initial text of the component or do you want to do more?

Comment: im generating random strings which i want to insert in ,y textareas using the methods i write.

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `initComponents()` method is generated by the IDE, each time you build the project it is regenerated (from separate xml). You have to "tell" the IDE that you are adding custom code.

- Go to your GUI editor, Click on the `JTextArea` component

[image]

- select `Properties` (in the sidebar under the palette), find `text` property, 
  click `ellipsis` (button with three dots)

[image]

- from the dialog that pops up select `custom code`, type the code that returns the string you want.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `initComponents()` method is regenerated by the IDE as you create your UI in the GUI editor. The method is 'guarded' to prevent this regeneration from overwriting user written code.

The initComponents method is read only to keep full control for the IDE. You may add yours in the constructor right after initComponents.

```
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public NewJFrame() {
    initComponents();
    myInitComponents();
}

public void myInitComponents() 
{
   jTextArea1.setText("some text"+yes());
}

public String yes(){
    return "voila";
}
```

Comment: but all my components are in initcomponents() tho, how would i access them using another function?

Comment: You must remove your components from initComponents () and place them in myInitComponents ()

Comment: ok i see. But does that mean i will constantly have to remove what is generated in initcomponent() ? if i add new components in the designer, the code will be generated in initcomponent each time...

Comment: @Barbell You do not have to eliminate what initComponent () generates, only what you have added, that is, remove all the code that you have added, but not the one that generates NetBeans

Comment: @Barbell Your code goes in myInitComponents () and you do not have to touch the one generated by the IDE in initializeComponents ()

Comment: @Barbell Please, if this answer has served you, mark it as accepted so that other readers know that it is the correct answer

Comment: i haven't added anything cause i can not edit the function initcomponent() , how can i write another function using the compenent in initcomponent() ? i dont understand.

Comment: Manuel Martinez Duran , thanks for your explanations

Comment: If you can not edit it, it means that you have not added your own code and that all the initComponents () code has been generated by Netbeans